# Executing php code by clicking a link

Tags: php, mysql

Good people i am stuck with an issue that i know has been discussed here before. I am displaying mysql data as a link and want to load more data from the database when a user clicks the link, I looked at all the previous questions and answers but i can't sort this one out. Here is how far i have managed to drag myself:

index.php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT topic FROM steps";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$topic = isset($_get['topic']);
$id = isset($_get['id']);

echo '<a href="moreinfo.php?id=' . $id . '">'.$row['topic'].'</a><br/>';
}
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

moreinfo.php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$id = isset($_get['id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM steps WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $topic = isset($_get['topic']);
     echo "Description: " . $row['topic'] . "<br />";


        }
}
else{
      echo "123";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This doesn't give me any error, just that the hyperlinks on this line
`echo '<a href="moreinfo.php?id=' . $id . '">'.$row['topic'].'</a><br/>';` 
on index.php does not append an id ($id) to the hyperlink so that moreinfo.php can execute correctly.
I rily pray i'm making some sense here...

Comment: `$_get` =/= `$_GET` Case sensitive

Comment: (1) `$_get` should be `$_GET` (2) `isset($_GET['id']);` is always going to be a boolean so your id will only ever be 1 or 0; you probably want something like `$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;`  (3) better to use a prepared statement with a bound parameter rather than interpolating the value into the SQL query (that way SQL injection lies).

Comment: `$id = isset($_get['id']);` should be `if ( isset($_GET['id'])){ $id = $_GET['id'];} else { exit;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `$_GET['id']` insted of `$_get['id']`
2. Correct usege of isset is looks like this 
   `$id = isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:false`
3. Always check if parameter which you will use next was really passed

   `$id     = isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:false;
   if(!$id)
       die('id was not passed');`
4. And last, you were overwriting variables from db with data from GET which should be on first page (probably copy and past )

   `$topic = isset($_get['topic']);
   $id = isset($_get['id']);`

here is your fixed code:
**index.php**

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM steps";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo '<a href="moreinfo.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['topic'].'</a><br/>';
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

**moreinfo.php**

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
    }
    $id     = isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:false;
    if(!$id)
        die('id was not passed');

    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM steps WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $topic = isset($_get['topic']);
            echo "Description: ".$row['topic']."<br />";
        }
    } else {
        echo "123";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

sql table create statement

```
CREATE TABLE `steps` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help good people, late response is probably due to time diferences and fact that i only acess internet at the office

Comment: if it helped you then select the answer =)

Answer (score -1):

Ok first thing first you are overwriting your id in this line

```
$id = isset($_get['id']);
```

so when you try to use it it holds bool value (true or false) instead of actual $id. And you do it in both of your files.

Comment: A suggested fix would convert this from a COMMENT into a possible Answer. If all you have is a comment, then use the comment feature

Comment: You also missed that `$_get` does not exist but `$_GET` just might